# Error assigning value to a static variable

Tags: visual-c++

> In this piece of code I don't know why the compiler doesn't let me assign the value 0 to variable x. I highlighted the line that cause the problem.

```
class List{
private:
    int p;
public:
    static int x;
    void total();
};

void List::total(List *a){
    x + = a -> p;
    cout<<x;
    getch();
    x=0; // problem here
}
```

> I also noticed that if I write int List::sum=0 before the function body, program works just fine. I just don't understand why. 
>   I appreciate any help!

Comment: _What error do you get_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the static in your class but have not defined a variable for it.

```
class List{
private:
    int p;
public:
    static int x;    // this is just a declaration
    void total();
};
```

You need to define it, normally in the associated cpp file:

```
List::x = 0;        // define variable and initialise
```

Quoting [from here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/class.html):

> **9.4.2  Static data members**
>   The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is
>   not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than 
>   cv-qualified   void.   The  definition  for  a  static  data member
>   shall appear in a   namespace scope enclosing the member's class
>   definition.  In the defi-   nition at namespace scope, the name of the
>   static data member shall be   qualified by its class name using the ::
>   operator.   The  initializer   expression  in  the definition of a
>   static data member is in the scope   of its class
>   (*basic.scope.class*).

Comment: Thank you very much, now it makes sense. It helped a lot in understanding the static variables!

Answer (score 0):

The operator `+=` tries to increase the value of `x`. You need to initialize `x` before using it.